# Perl: Config::Simple

Tags: perl, config

I am doing the config file using [Config::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Simple) module.

```
my $cfg = Config::Simple->import_from($config{'file'}, \my %config) 
  or die Config::Simple->error();
```

I am trying to import the variable from different file i.e `config` and in that variable called `file`.

And my `config` file

```
file=/etc/wvdial.conf
```

How would I do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What is `config` and what is `file`? Are those variable names? What variable do you want to import? Where is the line `fil/etc/wvdial.conf`? Is your current code working?

Answer (score 0):

Don't create two variables with the same name!

```
Config::Simple->import_from($config_qfn, \my %config) 
   or die(Config::Simple->error());

Config::Simple->import_from($config{file}, \my %config2) 
   or die(Config::Simple->error());

print($config2{x}, "\n");
```

Comment: What does the `qfn` in `$config_qfn` stand for?

Comment: @simbabque, "Qualified file name" (a relative or absolute path), in contrast to "fully qualified file name" (an absolute path). I reserve "file name" for just the file name part of the path.